# Could not load type "System.Web.HttpContext" from assembly "System.Web"

Tags: c#, .net

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Example : 
{
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/example.xml"));
}
```

Comment: do you have a reference to system.web?

Comment: You should accept the answer so people know that you're now good...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, if you are not in a web application, no way you can use the HttpContext.Current !

you can check if System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null or not, it's available only in web pages or web services.

Comment: The follow up question then is how to return a relative path without Server.MapPath in C#.

Comment: since the MapPath is relative to the current virtual directory or web site, does not make sense to use it in a non web application. if you simply want to change a relative path into an absolute path in any location of the file system, Server.MapPath is NOT what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Another issue is that the free community version seems to only work in .NET Framework and not .NET Core sadly.

Comment: 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web' not solution for Net Core 3.1 ?