# Unable to create instance of unit test class. Error: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I'm trying to create an instance of a class I need for a unit test. This class depends a "global object", which gets passed into the constructor. It basically gives the object access to our base return class that helps us handle errors and diagnostics (so I can't do without it in this architecture).

The problem is that a constructor a couple layers above the global object constructor relies on an assembly that can't be loaded when I instantiate my test class:

```cs
// test constructor
public Tests()
{
  State state = new State(GlobalObject);
}

// global object constructor
public Global()
{
  string localPath = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null)
                   ? string.Empty 
                   : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");

  ...
}

The error: 

Unable to create instance of class Tests. Error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'..
```

I've tried rebuilding the solution/cleaning the project. I've also tried adding this assembly manually, but this error persists. Search results for this question are either very old or not helpful. How can I get this assembly to be recognized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load type "System.Web.HttpContext" from assembly "System.Web"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925101/could-not-load-type-system-web-httpcontext-from-assembly-system-web)

Comment: @NigelBess Thank you but unfortunately no :( 
Our code checks if the assembly is null as the first answer suggests. Also we are running .NET framework enterprise as the second answer suggests.